# Not able to get the recurrence in outlook web app

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get the outlook recurrence value while in compose mode from the Outlook web

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync(val=>console.log(val)) // null
```

is returning null value

when tried to get through makeEwsRequestAsync getting error

**Error: Elevated permission is required to call the method: 'mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync'.**

```
<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
```

Comment: Did you try to get the recurrence just after doing a saveAsync?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, Thanks it did worked but in the case of the outlook desktop app without saving it is working.

Comment: Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, Yes the issue is resolved now. But there is a difference between the outlook web and the outlook desktop app. In the desktop app, the recurrence object is available without saving also.

Comment: Can you please give the exact repro steps? We tried setting the recurrence details using the recurrence api and then getting it. It worked without saving in OWA. Is that what that is tried here?